# Set size of border inside ControlTemplate to size of button

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate, wpf-style

I want a ControlTemplate for a few buttons so I can control the colour of the button when the mouse is over it. The problem is that I use a border as the ControlTemplate content and I want the size (BorderThickness) of that border to be equal to the button's size. And since the button is part of a grid, its size is flexible. This is my code so far:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTesting.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTesting"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="350">

<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ex">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Btn0" Margin="0, 10, 0, 30" Style="{StaticResource ex}" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Button Content="Btn1" Margin="0, 10, 0, 30" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button Content="Btn2" Margin="0, 10, 0, 30" Grid.Row="2"/> 
</Grid>
```

How can I make the BorderThickness fill the entire grid row. Should I even be using a border as the ControlTemplate content in the first place?

Comment: just use border Background: `<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">`

Comment: @ASh Thank you, the button is now the correct size but no content is showing up in it. Do you have any ideas on how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just write

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
        <ContentPresenter
            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the issue with the button being the wrong size. No content is showing up inside the button, however. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: You were missing `<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">`